# Tab separated text to CSV in C

Tags: c, regex, tabs, scanf

I need to read a tab-separated text from a file and then write it to the CSV file.
My problem is when I get to a part where there is more than one tab in a row. 
Given txt file is an address book, and has 37 values. When I encounter a tab, a should jump over it and read the next string. So when there is only one tab it works fine. But when there is more than one tab, my regex eats all the tabs until the next string and then reads it.
I need to read that "nothing" in-between the two tabs.
This problem results in storing a value to a field that is not meant for it. For example, I have fields firstName, lastName, fullName, and email. if there is no fullName value, there would be two tabs and then my code should store email value to email. Instead, it stores that value to the fullName field. Here is my code:

```
char* format = "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t"
        "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t"
        "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\n";
    fscanf(file, format, cont.firstName, cont.lastName, cont.displayName, cont.nickname, cont.primaryEmail, cont.secondaryEmail,
        cont.screenName, cont.workPhone, cont.homePhone, cont.faxNumber, cont.pagerNumber, cont.mobileNumber,`enter code here`
        cont.homeAddress, cont.homeAddress2, cont.homeCity, cont.homeState, cont.homeZipCode, cont.homeCountry,
        cont.workAddress, cont.workAddress2, cont.workCity, cont.workState, cont.workZipCode, cont.workCountry,
        cont.jobTitle, cont.department, cont.organization, cont.webPage1, cont.webPage2, cont.birthYear, cont.birthMonth, cont.birthDay,
        cont.custom1, cont.custom2, cont.custom3, cont.custom4, cont.notes);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just saved me an agony of trying.